# How to insert unique email into database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to insert unique email and want to display a message in form something like - **email is already exists**. 
When I save the new record, it should return some response which tells it's already present in the table.

Model Class

```
@PostMapping("/user")
public ModelAndView processRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid Users user, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView(landingPage);
    } else {
        try {
            userService.saveUser(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/user");
    }
}
```

JSP Page

```
<form:form action="${registerUrl}" modelAttribute="user" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        ...
        <c:if test="${user.userId eq null}">
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Register">
        </c:if>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Entity Class

```
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="users_generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_USERS", allocationSize=1)


    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name="LOGIN_NAME")
    private String loginName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Column(name="MAIL_ID", unique=true)
    private String mailId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
}
```

Comment: In your service class, simply throw some kind of `RuntimeException` if a user with the same email address is already existing. Use Spring exception handler to map the exception to a custom error representation, which you can work with in the client. Use the response code 400 for Bad Requests.

Answer (score 1):

Add unique key constraint on your column in database. If you are using hibernate it will throw **ConstraintViolation** exception when you try to insert duplicate email and on updation it will throw **DataIntegerityViolationException**.

Just catch these exceptions and return your error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate or jpa you can use like below. unique=true make sure the email column value will be unique.

```
@Column(name = "email", unique=true)
private String email;
```

Else you have to add a method to check this

```
if(userService.findUserByEmail() != null) {
 // User already exists
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting the error duplicate email key **** and so, I want to redirect on same page with some msg like- email already in use